# How Do You Resolve This Parameter Not Valid Error? (C#, VisualStudio, WinForms)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, visual-studio-2013

Apologies for being such an amateur, but this error pops up for every picture box every time I run the program. I tried re-importing the images and even deleting the pictureboxes, but the error always finds another picture box to work on (like it's intelligent or something).

What is the problem here and how do you fix this?

[image: Parameter is Not Valid]

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to share your problem. But there is something missing from your question. What is your goal and your difficulty? What have you done so far? Please try to better explain your issue, your dev env & data structures, as well as to share more code (no screenshot), some samples, images or sketches of the screen, & user stories or scenario diagrams. To help you improve your requests, please read [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) & [Writing the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question).

Comment: @OlivierRogier Thank you for the notes, but all I really want is to know what the scenarios are that cause this error.

Comment: The resource is not a supported image? What is SearchBar?

Comment: @OlivierRogier SearchBar.png is the image. Made in Photoshop. Saved in the Resources folder which is located within the auto-generated project folder.

Comment: I've just made a test: I added a picturebox to a winform and choose an image, and select import to local resource .resx a png. It works on my VS2017 that added `this.pictureBox1.Image = global::WindowsFormsAppTest.Properties.Resources.competence;`. You should redo the job (clear or delete the picture box, delete the image in the resource file, and add again). Perhaps a bad image format: try with another image or resave/convert the SearchBar.

Comment: @OlivierRogier I tried just re-importing the image and adding it. You're saying that I should re-add the whole picbox, right?

Comment: Have you actually added that Image to `Project->Properties->Resources->Images`? You should not use the `Resources` folder. That folder is used by Visual Studio. Avoid creating confusion between your working Images and the Images added to the Project Resources. Don't move or otherwise modify object stored in the `Resources` folder. If you want to remove an Image from the Project's Resources, remove the Images added to Controls in the Designer, then delete the object from the Project's `Resources`  using the `Resources` panel.

Comment: If you want to import a Bitmap as resource from the Designer, when you select the Image Property of a Control, use the `Import` button in the `Project resource file` section. As already mentioned, don't move this Image from the local storage folder. You can actually modify it and reflect the changes in all Controls that, eventually, use it. But that's [another story](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51254876/7444103).

Comment: Did you try to import the image via coding? Does that trigger an exception? Please note that you should call the image file in the using statement.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an image to a picture box as an embedded resource like that:

1. Put a PictureBox on the WinForm.
2. Select the quick action "Add image" or the "..." of the Image property.
3. Select "Project resource file" and import.

Delete the picture box and the embeded resource image in case of problem then retry, or do it with an empty project to see if it works fine with your VS.

Also try another image and/or check if your image has a good format or if it has an esoteric content: convert it to another format or save it again (with XnView, Gimp, Photoshop... for example).

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is how I did it. I'll try what you said before, two delete and re-add the boxes.